# Using a XML document instead of a String

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Okay so I got this Javascript code, and i use it to display some XML in HTML.

```
   var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find( "title" );

// Append "RSS Title" to #someElement
$( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );

// Change the title to "XML Title"
$title.text( "XML Title" );

// Append "XML Title" to #anotherElement
$( "#anotherElement" ).append( $title.text() );
```

But I would like to use an XML file instead of a string.
I tried something like this:

```
   var xml = $.get("myfile.xml"),
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find( "title" );

// Append "RSS Title" to #someElement
$( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );

// Change the title to "XML Title"
$title.text( "XML Title" );

// Append "XML Title" to #anotherElement
$( "#anotherElement" ).append( $title.text() );
```

(myfile.xml  would contain the same text as the string did)
Sorry if this is really obvious, im a newbie when it comes to JavaScript :D
PS: Just let me know in the comments if i forgot to mention something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get` is **asynchronous** by default.

Use:

```
$.get("myfile.xml", function (xml) {
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find( "title" );

  // Append "RSS Title" to #someElement
  $( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );

  // Change the title to "XML Title"
  $title.text( "XML Title" );

  // Append "XML Title" to #anotherElement
  $( "#anotherElement" ).append( $title.text() );
});
```